# tuple implatation in python

Tags: python, opencv, parsing, tuples

i have this code of a code that i made for text detection

```
def drawRedRectangleAroundPlate(imgOriginalScene, licPlate):
    p2fRectPoints = cv2.boxPoints(licPlate.rrLocationOfPlateInScene)            # get 4 vertices of rotated rect

    cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, tuple(p2fRectPoints[0]), tuple(p2fRectPoints[1]), SCALAR_RED, 2)         # draw 4 red lines
    cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, tuple(p2fRectPoints[1]), tuple(p2fRectPoints[2]), SCALAR_RED, 2)
    cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, tuple(p2fRectPoints[2]), tuple(p2fRectPoints[3]), SCALAR_RED, 2)
    cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, tuple(p2fRectPoints[3]), tuple(p2fRectPoints[0]), SCALAR_RED, 2)
# end function
```

and I have this trace back problem that I don't understand

```
cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, tuple(p2fRectPoints[0]), tuple(p2fRectPoints[1]), SCALAR_RED, 2)         # draw 4 red lines
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'line'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
```

Comment: See [ask]. Edit the title and the body for clearness and correctness. Also post a [mre].

Comment: Points must be integers not floats and two coordinates in a tuple for each end point.

Comment: Most likely, `p2fRectPoints[0]` *is* a tuple of x,y coordinates. Calling `tuple` makes it something else. Try just getting of the calls to `tuple` and pass the points direcy.

Comment: Also, I don't know what you meant by "implatation" so I didn't fix it. Consider using Google translate or some other similar service to find an English word. They are actually not too bad.

Comment: @rici ok here is the thing .people change my own damn question! it is just a simple question what the problem was and it just makes a bounding box for a code that detects car plates and to be honest i dont know so many things about py. im newbie as it gets and i just wanted a simple answer to what is should be. but every body explains it rather than giving the answer and most the time people just hate on me. man i dont know wtf tupple is!

Comment: @radyalz: A tuple is just like a list except that you cannot modify it once it is created. It's written with parentheses instead of brackets. (`(1, 2)` is a tuple; `[1, w]` is a list.) They are indexed the same way: `s[0]` is the first element of `s` regardless of whether `s` is a list or a tuple.

Comment: @radyalz, fmw42 already gave the answer. Do like this ```p2fRectPoints[0].astype(int)```.

Answer (score -1):

You wrote:

```
    cv2.line(imgOriginalScene, tuple(p2fRectPoints[0]), tuple(p2fRectPoints[1]), SCALAR_RED, 2)
```

The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga7078a9fae8c7e7d13d24dac2520ae4a2)
explains that `.line()` accepts

```
void cv::line   (   InputOutputArray    img,
        Point   pt1,
        Point   pt2,
        const Scalar &      color, 
        ... )
```

It appears that `p2fRectPoints` has four points, each with (x,y) coordinates.
So rather than using e.g. `tuple(x, y)` to construct a point from two integers,
it appears you can just pass in `p2fRectPoints[0]` as-is, with no
function call to `tuple`. You can verify this by examining `type(p2fRectPoints[0])`, which should be a `Point` (or `tuple`).

Comment: It doesn't matter to pass a tuple or ```numpy.array```. The point is the type of elements as fmw42 commented.

Comment: i search it actully this comment is not that bad but write now i dont have access to the code so i could chek if it could fix it 
ipresiate your time that u put